# Why os.listdir(dir): omits the first file when looping through all files in a folder?

Tags: python

I want to loop through all excel files in a dir and add them to a pandas df but the loop always omits the first file and/or gives an error "File not found"
This is my code that used to work but for some reason doesn't anymore ...

```
dir = "C:/Users/radoy/Programming/ML Chart Patterns/" 
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        
        df = pd.read_excel(filename)
        dimensions = df.shape
        
        period = dimensions[0]-1
        openval = df['Open'].tolist()
        high = df['High'].tolist()
        low = df['Low'].tolist()
        close = df['Close'].tolist()
        volume = df['Volume'].tolist()

        to_append = [period, openval, high, low, close, volume]
        print(filename)

    base_length = len(base_df)
    base_df.loc[base_length] = to_append
```

results in error **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ASYS Training.xlsx'**

But if I check the list of files in that same dir below:

```
for filename in os.listdir(dir):
    if filename.endswith(".xlsx"):
        print(filename)
```

I get all 8 files

```
ASYS Training.xlsx
BNTX Training.xlsx
CNTY Training.xlsx
DEN Training.xlsx
GBOX Training.xlsx
HSKA Training.xlsx
MGM Training.xlsx
MP Training.xlsx
```

I have checked that the file is not open by any other app
All files have exactly the same structure.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're reading a list of unqualified filenames from a different directory than your cwd. You need to prepend the directory path to the filename, or change your cwd first.

Comment: Phrased differently: `filename` is just that: the file name. It's not the full path: it doesn't contain the directory part.

Comment: It is **not** omitting the filename. The error happens because the *file* name is not enough to open the file - you need a *path* to that file. The same problem applies to every filename in the folder, but that isn't noticeable because the exception halts the program.

Comment: you have to use `os.path.join(dir, filename)` to create correct path to file.  - `df = pd.read_excel( os.path.join(dir, filename) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting your working directory using [`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) is one way you could solve this problem. I think using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib) is a better route though, because pathlib is more modern, has some really great features, and is well worth knowing. pathlib handles full paths better when working with files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# filename: listdirs.py

from pathlib import Path

p = Path("/tmp")
for filename in p.glob('*.xlsx'):
    print(f'{filename=}, {filename.exists()=}')
```

```
$ ./listdirs.py
filename=PosixPath('/tmp/CNTY Training.xlsx'), filename.exists()=True
filename=PosixPath('/tmp/HSKA Training.xlsx'), filename.exists()=True
filename=PosixPath('/tmp/MP Training.xlsx'), filename.exists()=True
filename=PosixPath('/tmp/GBOX Training.xlsx'), filename.exists()=True
filename=PosixPath('/tmp/DEN Training.xlsx'), filename.exists()=True
filename=PosixPath('/tmp/MGM Training.xlsx'), filename.exists()=True
filename=PosixPath('/tmp/ASYS Training.xlsx'), filename.exists()=True
filename=PosixPath('/tmp/BNTX Training.xlsx'), filename.exists()=True
```

The problem with `os` is that it's working with the bare filename, not the full path to the file. Those bare filenames expect the current working directory to be what you have defined as `dir`.

**Sidenote**: `dir` is a python builtin function. When you `dir = whatever` you overwrite that function. You should either use `_dir` or some other name.